# Do I just have to forget about lifting weights?

Tags: weight-loss, bodybuilding, cardio, body-fat

Started gym 2 months ago - 5 days a week (1 hour cardio, 1 hour weights).

145 pounds, 170cm, female.

I am eating a calorie deficit and realize my gains are only newbie gains..

I will forever be eating a calorie deficit as I cant see myself ever being happy with my body until I'm shredded as (eat about 1500 cals a day) so, when these newbie gains wear off, is it pointless me still lifting weights as it's impossible to gain muscle while in calorie deficit? or not pointless as it's important to maintain it?

Comment: Not pointless:  important to maintain.  Without weightlifting you will burn muscle to fuel your body, rather than fat.

Comment: Remember it's not all about weight. Body composition, the relative amount of lean tissue versus fat is arguably more important. You can gain weight lifting by gaining muscle and losing fat. And 5 days a week at that intensity is likely to result in becoming overtrained.

Answer (score 3):

[Load bearing exercises combined with a proper diet have been demonstrated to reduce and in some cases reverse bone density losses](http://www.webmd.com/osteoporosis/living-with-osteoporosis-7/weight-training). Women especially need to be aware of this as decreased bone density can lead to osteoporosis, which impacts women much more than men.

Additionally, [one of the biggest predictors of hospitalisation and poor health in later life is the ability to stand unaided from the floor](http://www.nbcnews.com/health/health-news/can-you-do-simple-sitting-test-predicts-longevity-f1C7588565).

**So for your health alone resistance training is vital to good health.**

Furthermore, getting "ripped" requires more than just low body fat but also for muscles to show off. Resistance exercise is the only reliable way to promote muscle growth. Even at a calorie deficit you will grow muscle, it will just happen very, very slowly. Eating at a surplus will grow your muscles fast, but the human body is a very complex system.

If you enjoy weight training, continue at it. Remember changes won't happen in days or weeks. but long-term perseverance with help you reach your goals.

Answer (score 1):

What I am able to understand from your question is that you want to be shredded, and if that is correct then I think your approach is wrong.

> I will forever be eating a calorie deficit as I cant see myself ever
>   being happy with my body until I'm shredded as (eat about 1500 cals a
>   day)

You need to get calories to perform daily activities let alone for strength training. My advice would be to

1. do not give up training.
2. increase protein in your diet and as well as good carbs such as from whole wheat pasta , sweet potato and raw eggs.Do not eliminate fat from your diet.Add fats from fish in your diet.
3. start with light weight and intense training (less time , more training). You might not be able to perform high intensity training right away but with time as stamina develops , you will be able to .
4. My personal belief is that to build good physique these are the contributing factors along with their weight: food : 60% , form : 15% , rest : 15 %, exercise : 10 %. Cutting short on any of these will result in incomplete results.

Comment: +1 I'd also say 'rest more', but seeing how that was suggested to her a week ago [in an answer to this extremely similar question of hers](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18289/calorie-restriction-connection-to-muscle-building) and she still goes all out 5 days a week, I won't :p

Answer (score -1):

It is necessary not to give up. Keep on with your weight lifting. However do not forget about a good cardio exercise. Even if your goal is to gain some muscle weight.

Comment: I downvoted your answer, because I don't think her current routine is healthy and 'not giving up' will just make things worse.